# Appium: How to switch to webview and select webElement without JSONWP Proxying in a hybrid app

Tags: java, webview, automated-tests, appium

I have heard that people use Webview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true).

Could anyone explain how to set up this in my test program? I try to import a android.jar to my program, but that cause some kind of problem like: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at the line of:

```
driver = new AppiumDriver<RemoteWebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), CAPA);
```

I wonder if this is necessary within my program if I want to switch to the webview. At this stage, if I try to switch the Webview, there will be a line of

> [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying[Get/status] to [Get http://XXXXX......] with no body

keep coming up within my appium server.

Answer (score 1):

**This property can not be set by Appium. This property is allowed to set in the source code of the app.**

Only, Developers can set the property. If you are developing the app you can set in the source code by your own. If not then ask your developer to set the property.

Comment: After it is set, there is still proxying problems coming up, May I ask how to fix it?

Comment: Don't try to switch the driver to webview. It will auto switch. Try identifying the elements on Android 6.0 or higher version through UIAutomator. It will show the elements inside the WEB VIEW.

Comment: I have seen your other answers, you mentioned that after running on the android 6.0 or above, it can run on other devices, am I right? Could there be other way to skip this procedure?

Comment: No. There is no other way to do this. UiAutomator itself detects the elements on Android 6.0 and the same script can be executed against lower OS versions like 5.0. If you don't have 6.0 device then you can try simulator or AVD